# Tools for microservice E2E automation testing

Tags: automated-testing, e2e, microservices

What are currently the best or most popular tools/solutions for automated end-to-end testing of microservices (preferably with an entry-level as low as possible)?

The CI/CD process is GitLab-based with deployment to a cloud platform if that's relevant.

Criteria:

- preferably low entry level for testers in terms of programming/scripting language;
- licencing is of no matter (solutions with a price tag are also welcome);
- e2e is meant between any given points in the process.

Comment: Welcome to SQA stack exchange. As it stands, your question is likely to be downvoted for being opinion-based - could you please edit to give your criteria and ask for tools that meet this criteria. For instance, do you want something that's free/open-source? Is there a preferred programming language? When you say end-to-end, do you mean end-to-end of the microservice, or end-to-end of the entire process? The more information we have, the more likely it is will be able to give you a good answer.

Comment: @KatePaulk, done. Is this enough from your point of view, or there's still room for improvement?

Comment: A couple of great articles [Testing Microservices, the sane way](https://copyconstruct.medium.com/testing-microservices-the-sane-way-9bb31d158c16) and one by [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/#conclusion-options)

Answer (score 2):

**Microservice testing:**

Microservice testing is same as any other API testing with a advantage that there is a contract defined for each endpoint meaning an expected output for an expected input, irrespective of the state of other components in the pool . This is because each microservice are individual process and need to be working independently.

**How to do microservice testing**

[image]

**Advantages of this:**

1. You will be testing individual microservices
2. You don't have to develop microservice but create mock servers that mimic response that the test target microservice expects other component
3. This strategy ensures each module works as expected and works when integrated together
4. Removes unwanted dependencies and adapts as microservice testing strategy

**Recommendations:**

You can use wiremock if you are using Java. But i recommends to migrate to postman as it supports mock servers inbuilt and it is really easy to use

https://blog.postman.com/postman-engineering-microservices-example/

Read more elaborated answer:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/46186/40022

### Update:

Read about distributed monolithic issue

[https://www.gremlin.com/blog/is-your-microservice-a-distributed-monolith/#:~:text=A%20distributed%20monolith%20is%20an,is%20built%20like%20a%20monolith.&text=In%20a%20monolithic%20architecture%2C%20the,required%20for%20it%20to%20run](https://www.gremlin.com/blog/is-your-microservice-a-distributed-monolith/#:%7E:text=A%20distributed%20monolith%20is%20an,is%20built%20like%20a%20monolith.&text=In%20a%20monolithic%20architecture%2C%20the,required%20for%20it%20to%20run)

THis was discussed in postman galaxy today it was a great talk, make sure your architecture doesn't cause this issue and each unit work individually and independently

Comment: thank you for your response. Could you clarify a bit what output is asserted on your scheme? Some specific type or any arbitrary?

Comment: @High it should be specific value , response code , response status ,and response schema ,

Comment: So if i understood you right, it lies on the mock-servers side, not on the side of 'side-effects' like further calls of other microservices etc.?

Comment: @HighPredator yes you don't have to check how the consumer is behaving if its a pure microservice infrastructure . Because even the consumer is an independent entity and should know how to handle expected outputs from the first service . The consumer will mock those response as its input

Comment: @HighPredator https://www.gremlin.com/blog/is-your-microservice-a-distributed-monolith/#:~:text=A%20distributed%20monolith%20is%20an,is%20built%20like%20a%20monolith.&text=In%20a%20monolithic%20architecture%2C%20the,required%20for%20it%20to%20run.  read about distributed monolithic microsevice . THis is a bad design so y=check if your system can have this issue. Thats why system testing is importatn

Comment: I Will do that, thanks!

Comment: @PDHide I don't understand how do you test integration ? using mocks doesn't guarantee correct integration between services

Comment: @Rsf that's why I mentioned about the distributed monolithic effect , each microservice should know the well defined contract on what happens when a service down ,what happens for a particular input . It's easy to have ripple effect in microservice environment

Comment: https://saucelabs.com/blog/4-best-practices-for-testing-microservices

Comment: https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/integration-tests-dont-cut-it-microservices-heres-what-does

Comment: So I gather that E2E testing where the second end is not the same microservice is not popular and somewhat not advised, right?